# PHP this preg_replace in C#

Tags: c#, php, regex

I've tried to convert the following preg_replace:

```
$text = preg_replace("|($word)|iu", "<span style=\"background: #DEF9D9; font-family: Arial;\">$1</span>", $text);
```

Into a C# code:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "|(" + word + ")|iu", "<span style=\"background: #DEF9D9; font-family: Arial;\">$1</span>");
```

But for some reason, the replacement is wrong. It puts the html tag (`<span ...></span`) and only after that, it puts the matched word (back-reference).

What's the problem here? (The PHP preg_replace works fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is unique in requiring you to write regexes as string literals **and** add regex delimiters (`|`, in your case).  The first thing you need to do is get rid of the pipes.  The `i` (case-insensitive) and `u` (Unicode) modifiers need to go, too.  You can make the regex case-insensitive by adding `(?i)` to the beginning of the regex (which works in PHP too, by the way).  The `u` is unnecessary; C# strings are always Unicode, and .NET's regex flavor is always in Unicode mode.

The C# version of that code would be:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "(?i)(" + word + ")", "<span style=\"background: #DEF9D9; font-family: Arial;\">$1</span>");
```

The reason you got the result you did is be cause the pipes are being treated as regex metacharacters--specifically, the [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), or "OR" operator.  If the target word happened to be "foo", your regex ended up being:

```
|(foo)|iu
```

...which matches either *nothing* (because of the *nothing* before the first pipe) or `foo` or `iu`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to escape the pipe characters:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "\\|(" + word + ")\\|iu", "<span style=\"background: #DEF9D9; font-family: Arial;\">$1</span>");
```

So the regular expression engine will interpret them as literal pipes instead of alternation operators.

Comment: The pipes and the `iu` are not supposed to be part of the regex.  They need to be removed, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: I never knew regular expressions worked in such a weird way in PHP. Thanks!